# "document.write" removes all duplicated spaces

Tags: javascript

I want to keep space when I use document.write();

```
var text = "many         spaces";
document.write(text);
```

But the output is "many spaces".

How to do that please?

PS: I've tried with innerHTML but it does the same:

```
<p id=demo></p> 
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "many      spaces";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not `document.write`, it's default behavior of how spaces are rendered. W3C specification explicitly [defines](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/text.html#h-9.1):

> Note that a sequence of white spaces between words in the source document may result in an entirely different rendered inter-word spacing (except in the case of the PRE element). In particular, user agents should collapse input white space sequences when producing output inter-word space.

If you want to preserve spaces you can either render content in [`<pre>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) tag:

```js
var text = "many         spaces";
document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

... or use `white-space: pre` CSS rule:

```js
var text = "many         spaces";
document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = text;
```

```css
div { white-space: pre;}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

There is one more option, using `&nbsp;` however I would not recommend it since this not the *same* at all as normal white space character (because it's non-breaking). It is also can be non convenient to convert original text spaces into `&nbsp;`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `&nbsp;` wich means **Non Breaking SPaces;**

So write this :

```
    var text = "many &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; spaces";
```

The reason is that HTML simplifies the text display. There are many reasons in web programming to produce many white spaces that have no interest. So it's easier to remove duplicate spaces than to try to avoid these duplicates.

If you want add space for better display, you should probably also use CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `&nbsp;` instead of blank space.

This is what I would do:

```
var text = "many         spaces";
document.write(text.replace(' ', '&nbsp;'));
```

Note that this is not a problem with `document.write`, rather how the blank spaces are rendered in HTML.